# UIImageView with 1 pixel wide and 480 high gradient image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have gradient in my application, and my designer has made me a gradient image that is 1 pixel wide and 480 in height. How do I use this to make UIImageView stretched to full screen to make a fullscreen gradient image?

These two do not work, I get grey screen all the time:

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"];

myImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(480, 1, 0, 1)];
```

Comment: what about [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; ?

Comment: @PavelKatunin this has worked, would you consider making answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: I have posted the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f)];
```

Just fix UIEdgeInsets

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method, and pass UIEdgeInsetsZero:

```
myImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `colorWithPatternImage:` is easy for this:

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:gradientImage]]
```